# App Store - Unable to add testflight to build group

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, app-store-connect

I have published my app to testflight and it is "ready to submit" [ready to submit here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QIqL.png), however when I am trying to add it to my external testing build group it keeps showing an error[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIWAH.png), so I am not really sure what is wrong with it. My previous build have no issues , but ever since I encountered this problem all my previous build got expired too[expired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2cKS.png). Please help

Answer (score -1):

I also had this problem, and all previous commits were invalid. The latest committed version cannot be added to external testing.

Comment: ye same contacted apple but they said they are still checking it out , not sure if anyone had fixed this issue

Comment: how long did it take you to fix this issue ?